# Pivot table with n/m format in cell - two values separated with slash

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table that contains aggregated data like this:

```
Name | Data       | Status | Count
----------------------------------
A    | 2017-06-01 | ok     | 2
A    | 2017-06-01 | error  | 5
A    | 2017-06-02 | ok     | 3
A    | 2017-06-02 | error  | 1
A    | 2017-06-03 | ok     | 5
B    | 2017-06-01 | ok     | 1
B    | 2017-06-01 | error  | 7
B    | 2017-06-02 | ok     | 3
B    | 2017-06-02 | error  | 3
B    | 2017-06-03 | error  | 2
```

Now I'm trying to create pivot table with names as columns and date as rows. Inside cell I'd like to get number or rows with ok status to number of rows with error status in format `2/5`

Below is table I'd like to get:

```
Data       | A   | B 
------------------------
2017-06-01 | 2/5 | 1/7
2017-06-02 | 3/1 | 3/3
2017-06-03 | 5/- | -/2
```

Because I can have different values in `Name` column I've created dynamic query to get those values.

My code looks like this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT
        Name
      FROM
        TMP
    ) AS Courses


SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'SELECT Data, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM TMP
    PIVOT(SUM(Count)
          FOR Name IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'


EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

but I get twice much rows (probably because I'm not grouping by Status).

How can I get result I need?

I've build sample in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31770/3

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate TotalOk/TotalError before pivoting

```
CREATE TABLE TMP
    (
     Name VARCHAR(50)
    ,Data VARCHAR(10)
    ,Status VARCHAR(20)
    ,Count INT
    )
;

INSERT INTO TMP
    (Name, Data, Status,Count)
VALUES
    ('A', '2017-06-01', 'ok',2),
    ('A', '2017-06-01', 'error',5),
    ('A', '2017-06-02', 'ok',3),
    ('A', '2017-06-02', 'error',1),
    ('A', '2017-06-03', 'ok',5),
    ('B', '2017-06-01', 'ok',2),
    ('B', '2017-06-01', 'error',5),
    ('B', '2017-06-02', 'ok',3),
    ('B', '2017-06-02', 'error',1),
    ('B', '2017-06-03', 'error',2)
;

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT
        Name
      FROM
        TMP
    ) AS Courses


SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'
    SELECT Data, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM 
    (   SELECT 
      t.Name, t.Data,
      CONCAT(    NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN t.Status = ''ok'' THEN t.Count ELSE 0 END),0),
             ''/'', 
             NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN t.Status = ''ok'' THEN 0 ELSE t.Count END),0)
            ) AS Count
       FROM dbo.TMP t
       GROUP BY t.Name, t.Data
    ) src
    PIVOT
    (
       MAX(Count)
        FOR Name IN (' + @ColumnName + ')
    ) AS PVTTable'


EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery


DROP TABLE dbo.TMP
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/TMAVV39610

Answer (score 0):

Sample data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #Temp
;With cte(Name , Data, Status , [Count])
AS
(
SELECT 'A','2017-06-01' , 'ok'     , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','2017-06-01' , 'error'  , 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','2017-06-02' , 'ok'     , 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','2017-06-02' , 'error'  , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','2017-06-03' , 'ok'     , 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B','2017-06-01' , 'ok'     , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B','2017-06-01' , 'error'  , 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B','2017-06-02' , 'ok'     , 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B','2017-06-02' , 'error'  , 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B','2017-06-03' , 'error'  , 2
)
SELECT * INTO #Temp From cte

SELECT * FRom #Temp
```

The below approach give your expected result by dynamic sql approach

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@ColumnName2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ QUOTENAME(Name) FROM  #Temp FOR  XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @ColumnName2=
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ 'REPLACE(ISNULL('+ QUOTENAME(Name) +','+'''0'''+')'+','+'''0'''+','+'''-'''+') AS '
                           + QUOTENAME(Name) FROM  #Temp FOR  XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')


SET @DynamicPivotQuery=N'
                        ;With Cte
                          AS
                            (
                                SELECT Data,'+@ColumnName2+'From 
                                (
                                SELECT * FROM #Temp 
                                ) AS SRC
                            PIVOT
                                (
                                SUM([Count]) FOR Name IN ('+@ColumnName+')
                                )
                            PVT
                            )
                            SELECT Data ,[A],[B]
                                    FROM (
                                        SELECT DATA ,STUFF((SELECT ''/'' + CAST([A] AS VARCHAR(5))  FROM CTE I
                                                    WHERE I.DATA = O.DATA ORDER BY 1 DESC
                                                    FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 1, '''') AS [A]
                                            ,STUFF((
                                                    SELECT ''/'' + CAST([B] AS VARCHAR(5))  FROM CTE I
                                                    WHERE I.DATA = O.DATA ORDER BY 1 
                                                    FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 1, '''') AS [B]
                                            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATA ORDER BY DATA ) AS SEQ
                                        FROM CTE O
                                        ) DT
                                    WHERE DT.SEQ = 1
                            '

PRINT @DynamicPivotQuery

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Static approach

```
 ;WITH cte
    AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT Data
            ,REPLACE(ISNULL([A], '0'), '0', '-') AS [A]
            ,REPLACE(ISNULL([B], '0'), '0', '-') AS [B]
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM #Temp
            ) AS SRC
        PIVOT(SUM([Count]) FOR NAME IN (
                    [A]
                    ,[B]
                    )) PVT
        )
    SELECT Data
        ,[A]
        ,[B]
    FROM (
        SELECT DATA
            ,STUFF((
                    SELECT '/' + CAST([A] AS VARCHAR(5))
                    FROM CTE I
                    WHERE I.DATA = O.DATA
                    ORDER BY 1 DESC
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '') AS [A]
            ,STUFF((
                    SELECT '/' + CAST([B] AS VARCHAR(5))
                    FROM CTE I
                    WHERE I.DATA = O.DATA
                    ORDER BY 1
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '') AS [B]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY DATA ORDER BY DATA
                ) AS SEQ
        FROM CTE O
        ) DT
    WHERE DT.SEQ = 1
```

Result

```
Data       | A   | B 
------------------------
2017-06-01 | 2/5 | 1/7
2017-06-02 | 3/1 | 3/3
2017-06-03 | 5/- | -/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can give you an Idea.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
 IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TMP') IS NOT NULL)
 BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TMP

 END

   CREATE TABLE #TMP 
    (
      id INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
             PRIMARY KEY ,
      NAME VARCHAR(10) ,
      DATA DATETIME ,
      [Status] VARCHAR(20) ,
      [Count] INT
    )
   DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
   INSERT   INTO #TMP
            ( NAME, DATA, Status, Count )
   VALUES   ( 'A', '2017-06-01', 'ok', 2 ),
            ( 'A', '2017-06-01', 'error', 5 ),
            ( 'A', '2017-06-02', 'ok', 3 ),
            ( 'A', '2017-06-02', 'error', 1 ),
            ( 'A', '2017-06-03', 'ok', 5 ),
            ( 'B', '2017-06-01', 'ok', 1 ),
            ( 'B', '2017-06-01', 'error', 7 ),
            ( 'B', '2017-06-02', 'ok', 3 ),
            ( 'B', '2017-06-02', 'error', 3 ),
            ( 'B', '2017-06-03', 'error', 2 )
```

QUERY:

```
   DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

   SELECT   @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(Name)
   FROM     ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        Name
              FROM      #TMP
            ) AS Courses

  SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'

   SELECT   CAST(DATA AS DATE) DATA,
            ' + @ColumnName + '
   FROM     ( SELECT    name ,
                        data ,
                        REPLACE(CAST([A] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ''/''
                                + CAST([B] AS VARCHAR(10)), ''0'', ''-'') COL
              FROM      ( SELECT    t1.name ,
                                    t1.data ,
                                    ISNULL(t1.COUNT, 0) [A] ,
                                    ISNULL(T2.Count, 0) [B]
                          FROM      ( SELECT    NAME ,
                                                DATA ,
                                                Status ,
                                                Count
                                      FROM      #TMP
                                      WHERE     Status = ''ok''
                                    ) T1
                                    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  NAME ,
                                                        DATA ,
                                                        Status ,
                                                        Count
                                                FROM    #TMP
                                                WHERE   Status = ''error''
                                              ) T2 ON T2.NAME = T1.NAME
                                                      AND T2.DATA = T1.DATA
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT    t2.name ,
                                    t2.data ,
                                    ISNULL(t1.COUNT, 0) [A] ,
                                    ISNULL(T2.Count, 0) [B]
                          FROM      ( SELECT    NAME ,
                                                DATA ,
                                                Status ,
                                                Count
                                      FROM      #TMP
                                      WHERE     Status = ''error''
                                    ) T2
                                    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  NAME ,
                                                        DATA ,
                                                        Status ,
                                                        Count
                                                FROM    #TMP
                                                WHERE   Status = ''ok''
                                              ) T1 ON T2.NAME = T1.NAME
                                                      AND T2.DATA = T1.DATA
                        ) TT
            ) P PIVOT ( MAX(col) FOR name IN ( '+ @ColumnName + ' ) ) PVT'


        EXEC(@DynamicPivotQuery)
```

RESULT:

```
            DATA        A           B
            ----------  ----------- ----------
            2017-06-01  2/5         1/7
            2017-06-02  3/1         3/3
            2017-06-03  5/-         -/2

            (3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you wrote wrong data in your fiddle for B (so maybe you can't see partial expected result).
I think you can try something like this (I just changed a bit the last query, to aggregate 'ok' and 'error' in a string:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT
        Name
      FROM
        TMP
    ) AS Courses   

    SET @DynamicPivotQuery ='
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT Data, NAME, MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS=''ok'' THEN CAST(COUNT AS VARCHAR(8)) 
            ELSE ''-'' END)   +''/''
        + MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS=''error'' THEN CAST(COUNT AS VARCHAR(8)) ELSE ''-'' END)  AS C   
        FROM TMP  
        GROUP BY DATA, NAME) X
        PIVOT ( MAX(C) FOR Name IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'   

    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Output:

```
Data        A   B
2017-06-01  2/5 1/7
2017-06-02  3/1 3/3
2017-06-03  5/- -/2
```

**UPDATED VERSION:**

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery ='
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT Y.DATA, Y.NAME,   MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS=''ok'' THEN CAST(COUNT AS VARCHAR(8)) ELSE ''-'' END)   +''/''
    + MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS=''error'' THEN CAST(COUNT AS VARCHAR(8)) ELSE ''-'' END)   AS C  
    FROM TMP
    RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TMP.NAME, Z.DATA
                FROM TMP  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DATA FROM TMP ) Z) Y ON TMP.NAME = Y.NAME AND TMP.DATA = Y.DATA   
    GROUP BY Y.DATA, Y.NAME) X
    PIVOT ( MAX(C) FOR Name IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
```

Comment: sorry for bad data. I've checked Your example but for some reasons I get NULL if there are entries missing for specific Name: http://rextester.com/OSFH45159  I've tried adding isnull around max, but without luck

Comment: What value do you want if there are entries missing?

Comment: simple `-/-` will be fine

Comment: Me too: see if my sol it's the same (see updated version, at the end: I posted just the new string sql)